# SSH, Putty and sending data on the cluster

Tags: bash, scripting, putty

I have ssh access to the cluster through Putty. I also have the script, which, after its launch, makes some commands, generates data and sends it via email.

Is it possible to provide following: I send some command through Putty with some data, which initializes the script and makes it to run authomatically?

Comment: do you want to create a command that performs a sequence of actions, or you want to have putty perform that sequence of actions upon connection? You can do the latter, but you have to configure each connecting putty to do that (i.e. it wouldn't be useful as a security measure for tracking every logon).

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister : sorry, I want to do following: first putty send the file on the cluster. Once the file is received, the script which is located in cluster (and which uses data from sended file) authomatically launchs.

Comment: how (with putty) do you send the file? putty-cp?

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister : I expect that I will do that through scp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scp` provides file copy over an ssh connection, so the ability of ssh to automatically execute a command upon connection is what scp uses to copy the file(s), so you can't tap on that.

You have two options:

1) copy the file via ssh from a linux/cygwin host:

```
cat local-file | ssh host 'cat > remote-file & your-command'
```

2) run a cron job to monitor a given folder (`/folder` in the example below) and process the files (one by one, first moving the file elsewhere (to `/processed/` in the example below) so it's no longer picked up, then processed with your script (`your-command` in the example below, with the file to process as its argument).

```
* * * * * find /folder -type f -mmin +1 -maxdepth 1 | while read file; do mv "$file" /processed/; your-command "/processed/${file##*/}"; done
```

Make sure you add `-mmin +1` (modified over one minute ago) otherwise files may be processed whilst being copied.